# Singleton and multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

Please, look at the classes below and tell me if the code below is thread safe. The point of my question is that one class whose `static` method and that method calls singleton instance's method. Also, the `static` method is invoked by `Runnable` instance. So I am asking you guys to see the codes - `static` method and it calls singleton's method in multi thread environment - is safe?

I will really appreciate if you answer my question.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class SingletonCls {
    private static SingletonCls singletonInstance = null;

    private SingletonCls() {
    }

    public static SingletonCls getIntance() {
        if (SingletonCls.singletonInstance == null) {
            singletonInstance = new SingletonCls();
        }
        return SingletonCls.singletonInstance;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> call(String id) throws Exception {
        List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        final String col = "col";
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
            String lineStr = null;
            while ((lineStr = br.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(lineStr, ",");
                int colIdx = 1;

                if (lineStr.startsWith(id)) {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        String value = st.nextToken();
                        map.put(col + (colIdx++), value);
                    }
                    list.add(map);
                }
            }

        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestSingleTonCaller {

    public static List<Map<String, String>> getData(String id) throws Exception {
        List<Map<String, String>> list = SingletonCls.getIntance().call(id);
        return list;
    }
}



import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RunnableSingleTonExe implements Runnable {
    private final String id;

    public RunnableSingleTonExe(String inId) {
        this.id = inId;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            List<Map<String, String>> list = TestSingleTonCaller
                    .getData(this.id);
            System.out.println("thread id:" + this.id + "  list > "
                    + (list == null ? "" : list.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're not creating a singleton correctly, no. There's no guarantee you will only have one instance of `SingletonCls`. Use an `enum` in Java for singletons

Comment: `SingletonCls#getInstance` method is not thread safe. It would be better to initialize `singletonInstance` from the beginning instead of lazy loading it.

Comment: @Yoonyou Ryu - As Brain and Luiggi indicate, this is not threadsafe and there are better approaches.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635396/pattern-for-lazy-thread-safe-singleton-instantiation-in-java for other ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you all n your kind answer. I also totally agree with you. I just made the codes to simulate what my forks made. And I can be sure that codes are not safe n good. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe because this scenario can happen:

```
Thread 1                Thread 2
--------                --------
test instance != null
                        test instance != null
                        finds it is
finds it is
creates, assigns
                        creates, assigns
                        returns
returns
```

In essence, this is not a singleton anymore.

Note also that you cannot guarantee which created instances either thread will return since `singletonInstance` is not even volatile!

Easy fix, since your constructor does nothing:

```
private static final SingletonCLS INSTANCE = new SingletonCLS();

public static SingletonCLS getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }
```

Other possible solutions:

- use an enum;
- use a lazy initialization holder class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) I also told my co-worker about such scenario but he didn't listen. But I can be sure that code have wrong. i am gonna tell him again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't think you need a Singleton here.  You have no Instance Variable in the singleton Class. **The method could be static very Well**.  Therefore its Thread Safe in the Context that Singleton is not needed.

Second, Your Singleton is wrong (if it is required). Please refer **Effective Java Item 71.
try using (lazy initialization holder class idiom)**.

Second It may not be a good idea opening the same file again and again. better read and cache the data in memory and then try finding id. In this case you will need a SingleTon Object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. N I also think lazy initialization is not necessary. I am gonna get my co-worker to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getIntance()` method is not thread-safe. And this could lead to creation of more than one object of `SingletonCls` as specified in above answers.
To get the Singleton version of your class with lazy instantiation you should use following code:

```
public class SingletonCls 
{
    public static SingletonCls getInstance()
    {
        return LazyClass.getInstance();
    }
    private static class LazyClass
    {
        public static SingletonCls instance = new SingletonCls();
        public static SingletonCls getInstance()
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

This relies on the fact that inner classes are not loaded until they are referenced. This way of creating Singleton class is called as [Initialization on Demand Holder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom)

Comment: Thank for that link of lazy initialization holder. I will let my co-worker know the link and use the singleton holder if he insist to use lazy initialization. Thanks again.