# singleton design pattern with thread safe

Tags: singleton

I read the reason for synchronize the new instance creation is two threads can access getInstance same time and find that _instance is null and create two instances of Singleton class. So in order to eliminate that we synchronized it. But again how come a double-checked locking method introduce again check whether the instance is null inside the Synchronized block. Does this necessary? Once a code block is synchronized it already thread safe know?

```
public class Singleton {
        private static Singleton _instance = null;

        private Singleton() {   }

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
                if (_instance == null) {
                      synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                          _instance = new Singleton(); // why need to again check null
                      }
                }
                return _instance;
        }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pattern for lazy thread-safe singleton instantiation in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635396/pattern-for-lazy-thread-safe-singleton-instantiation-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized` block will be executed sequentially (i.e., one thread at a time), but that's not enough, because the second call to `_instance = new Singleton()` might override the first one.

It's a plausible scenario if one context-switch takes place immediately after the first thread evaluates the `_instance == null` expression, and no other context-switch takes place until another thread evaluates the `_instance == null` expression.

Therefore, once inside the `synchronized` block, the current thread has to make sure that `_instance` is still `null` before setting it to a `new Singleton()`.