# Please explain initialization safety as spelled out in Java memory model

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, java-memory-model

1. Can some one explain **initialization safety** as required by Java memory model ?
2. How does the **final** fields help in achieving *initialization safety* ?
3. What role does the **constructor** play in ensuring *initialization safety* ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Initialization safety provides for an object to be seen by an external thread in its fully constructed (initialized) state. The prerequisite is that the object should not be published prematurely ie. in its constructor. Once this is ensured, JMM requires certain behavior for the fields that are declared as `final`. First, all `final` object fields are guaranteed to be seen by an external thread in its fully initialized state. This is not as trivial as it sounds.

Consider a class:

```
class A {
   List list;
   A() {  
      list = Arrays.asList(some init expressions that adds 10 elements to list);
    }

}
```

A thread that accesses the `list` of `A's` instance is not by default guaranteed to see 10 elements in that list. In fact, this thread can even see `list` as `null`. However, if `list` is declared `final`, then, as required by JMM, the `list` must always appear to be initialized with 10 elements in it.

Secondly, this initialization guarantee is not limited to the `final` field itself but is extended recursively to all objects referred by it. For example, if the `list` in the above example is a list of lists themselves, then the external thread is guaranteed to see the inner lists as fully initialized.

Note that nowhere are we using `synchronized` to achieve this safety in memory visibility (happens-before relationship).

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the initilization safety not only guarantees safety for the final fields but also for objects that are referenced by final fields.

Answer (score 4):

**1.**
Initialization safety allows properly constructed **immutable objects to be shared safely across threads without using synchronization**, irrespective of even if they published using a data race.

**2.**
Objects having final field, initialization safety **prevent reordering any part of construction** with the initial load of a reference to that object.

Comment: "irrespective of even if they published using a data race." This line doesn't make any sense at all . Objects are not published using data races:-).

Comment: I'm not sure about "prevent reordering any part of construction". Guarantees for final fields only take effect for initialization of that final fields, not other parts of construction.

Comment: @axtavt actually reordering is prevented by making a field volatile not final. So point 2 is incorrect according to me .