# JCIP - Unsafe publication and happens before for a publishing thread

Tags: java, multithreading

**Listing 3.15. Class at Risk of Failure if Not Properly Published.**

```
public class Holder {
 private int n;
 public Holder(int n) { this.n = n; }    

 public void assertSanity() {
     if (n != n)
     throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
 }
}
```

if the Holder in Listing 3.15 is published using the unsafe publication idiom in Listing 3.14, and a thread ***other***
than the publishing thread were to call assertSanity, it could throw AssertionError!
[15]

**Listing 3.14. Publishing an Object without Adequate Synchronization. Don't Do this.**

```
// Unsafe publication
public Holder holder;
public void initialize() {
 holder = new Holder(42);
}
```

a) The first query is related to the **publishing thread itself**, and no other thread. If the publishing thread does something like below-

```
1. Holder holder = new Holder (5); 
2. holder.getN() // is it guaranteed that this will print 5
```

> By the Program order rule. Each action in a thread happens before
>   every action in that thread that comes later in the program order.

Since `1 hb 2` due to the above rule, 2 will be able to see that the assignment of obj to holder properly.

But is it guaranteed that 2 will also be able to see the safe construction of the holder object **without final modifier prefixed to n declaration**?

Does `public Holder(int n) { this.n = n; }` hb `1`?

Comment: What does `hb` mean?

Comment: If I correctly understood you, the question is "is there a way to raise AssertionError from the observer thread?" The answer is yes, the author describes the way in footnote #16. Mainly it is related with possible "stale" value of field `n`. The avoidance of the problem is described in 3.5.2. In addition, the problem is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11306032/1147388