# is FindBugs 'JLM_JSR166_UTILCONCURRENT_MONITORENTER' safe to ignore in this case

Tags: java, static, initialization, findbugs

I have a library that I am required to use that has a dangerous initialization of a static value (the classes have been stripped down to the minimum for the example):

```
public TheirBaseClass {
    public static String PathToUse = null;

    public BaseClass(){
        PathToUse = "Configured";

        // ... 
        // do some other stuff with other side effects 
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have a case where I attempt to read from the value `ConfigValue` without instantiating the class (to avoid some of the sideeffects).

```
Paths.get(TheirBaseClass.PathToUse).toFile()....
```

This causes a `NullPointerException`

Because I am required to use this class, I am looking to inherit from it, and attempt to take action to ensure that initialization has taken place when accessing the static.

```
public MyBaseClass extends TheirBaseClass{

    private static final AtomicBoolean isInitialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    static {
        MyBaseClass.Initialize();
    }

    public static void Initialize(){
        // FindBugs does not like me synchronizing on a concurrent object
        synchronized(isInitialized){
            if( isInitialized.get() ){
                return;
            }
            new TheirBaseClass();
            isInitialized.set(true);
        }
    }

    public MyBaseClass(){
        super();
    }

}
```

Which allows me to

```
MyBaseClass.Initialize();
Paths.get(MyBaseClass.PathToUse).toFile()....
```

This seems to be working reasonably well (and resolves some other phantom defects we've been having). It allows `TheirBaseClass` to function naturally, while allowing me to safely force initialization in the couple of cases I may need to.

However when I run FindBugs against this code, I get `JLM_JSR166_UTILCONCURRENT_MONITORENTER`. After reading the description, I agree that the use of `AtomicBoolean` could be dangerous because someone else could change the value, but...

1. I think its safe to ignore in this case (but have a doubt)
2. I generally prefer to rewrite code than put an ignore marker in place

Am I actually doing something dangerous (and just don't see it)? Is there a better way to do this?

Unfortunately, using a different `TheirBaseClass` is not an option.

**Related**

- [Are Java static initializers thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878577/are-java-static-initializers-thread-safe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it easier to adapt the [lazy holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom):

```
public MyBaseClass {
  private static class Initializer {
    static {
      new TheirBaseClass();
    }

    // Doesn't actually do anything; merely provides an expression
    // to cause the Initializer class to be loaded.
    private static void ensureInitialized() {}
  }

  {
    Initializer.ensureInitialized();
  }

  // Rest of the class.
}
```

This uses the fact that class loading happens only once and is synchronized (within a single class loader). It happens only when you instantiate a `MyBaseClass`.

Comment: I think I made a massive mistake in my example: I didn't extend `TheirBaseClass`

Comment: I had to ponder this. I am already implementing `lazy holder`. Your answer is correct, but the confusion seems to arise around the boolean: it is completely unecessary. I introduced that for a specific case, but that case seems to have gone away with more and more refactoring.

Comment: The boolean is unnecessary *if I make the initializer private*