# Single instance of a variable across entire application in multi-threading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, volatile

I have this below code.

```
private static volatile Properties props = null;
    private static volatile StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = null;
    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    static {
        if (props == null) {
            props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
        }
        if (pipeline == null) {
            pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        }
    }
```

**I want to have a single instance of variable `props` and `pipeline` across my entire application which is multithreaded**.

Is my code right or I am missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to check for nulls. It's not like they could be initialized before the static block runs.

Comment: What sort of application is this?

Comment: @chrylis maven 20 threaded using executor service

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Is this a CLI application, GUI, Web, something else?

Comment: @chrylis web based

Comment: Then use dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get rid of the `volatile` by using a method call and still retain thread safety through static initialization.

```
private static final Properties props = initProperties();
private static Properties initProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
    return props;
}

public static Properties getProperties() {
    return props;
}
```

Edit:
To answer your question though, **yes your  code in OP is indeed thread safe**, although what I've given before is the way that I would do it personally.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems right as you are creating the instance at class loading time, so you only have to create the getters for them

But i recommend using the singleton pattern in this case as shown below

i have used singleton pattern with double locking for multi threaded environment

```
public class Utility{

        private static final Object masterLock = new Object();
        private static volatile Properties props = null;
        private static volatile StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = null;

        static Properties getPropertiesInstance(){

            if(props == null){

                synchronized (masterLock) {
                    if(props == null){
                        props = new Properties();
                    }
                }
            }

            return props;
        }

        static StanfordCoreNLP getStanfordCoreNLPInstance(){

            if(pipeline == null){

                synchronized (masterLock) {
                    if(pipeline == null){
                        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP();
                    }
                }
            }

            return pipeline;
        }
}
```

Comment: kindly make necessary changes in the 'if' condition of both synchronized blocks

Comment: Yes, singleton will work. I too have used it several times. But in my above code won't new objects are creating when every thread is loading this class.

Comment: didn't understood about the object creation you're talking about "but in my  above code won't new objects . . . . ."

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` is not needed in your case. Java guarantees that the static initialization is properly synchronized. There is also no need for a method call. Also see [Are Java static initializers thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878577/are-java-static-initializers-thread-safe) and https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html